# Apache Ivy: Where do I put all these JARs?

Tags: apache, ant, maven, ivy

I'm trying to convince the higher-ups at my work place to migrate to Apache Ivy. I've managed to get a few sandbox projects working using Ivy to power the build, and now I have a greenlight to put together a migration proposal.

We all agree on one thing: we don't want to trust JARs that are located in public directories! I know, I know, a bit paranoid, yes. But we'd like to have a setup where we pull a JAR from a trusted source (either downloading it from the open source project itself, or most likely, gulp, a public repo), and use it for some time before we "*certify*" it (give it our blessing as a safe artifact to use).

Then we want to have a common repository for all JARs used by our many projects.

My original thinking was to place this repository up in version control (we have an SVN server). But I wasn't sure what best practices dictate. It might make more sense to put our JARs on a file server and FTP to them in the Ivy script.

Either way, SVN (HTTPS) or FTP, all of our servers are authenticated. So, a small number of questions:

1. Where should we be publishing all of our "certified" JARs (everything from `log4j` to any homegrown JARs we produce)? What do best practices dictate?
2. The "ivyrep" resolver-type does not take username or passwd atrributes. If our "JAR server" (FTP, SVN, etc.) is authenticated, how do I configure the Ivy scripts to login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use something like Sonatype's [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/). I've seen it used for Maven, and I believe it'll work for Ivy.

You can set it up to download from remote repositories into (say) a 'test' repository. You can then evaluate those .jars, and if they're good, upload them into an 'approved' repository for general consumption. There's some authentication surrounding this, but you'd have to evaluate that in greater depth. Certainly you can restrict the uploading into repositories via a username/password pair.

Comment: Thanks @Brian - I appreciate the suggestion but because I am trying to get this approved the repository *needs* to be an in-house server. It's going to be tough enough getting approval to use one new tool (Ivy), let alone two new tools (Sonatype). Don't worry about our internal approval process...just curious where JARs usually go... SCM servers, file servers, etc. And how to authenticate to those servers. Thanks!

Comment: Nexus _is_ a server that you can run in-house. It's built around serving artifacts (jars, ears, wars, etc, etc). SCM's aren't really that good at versioning binaries (at least not as effectively as non-binary files), so that's the point of having something like Nexus (which is very similar to Archiva or Artifactory as well--any of which would work for what you need).

Comment: If you don't want to push your luck by introducing another tool, you could just stand up an Apache web server as your repository.  That's what I did for my grassroots sandbox initiative.  It wasn't long before Ivy became official and we moved to Artifactory as our repository server.

Answer (score 2):

I must echo Brian's recommendation to use a repository manager like [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/). It's a lot less work in the long run. You'll also discover that the professional version of Nexus enables you to create approval processes around repositories which you plan to use in your build. See the [procurement suite](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/procure.html) functionality.

If, on the other hand, you are determined to build your own repository, then ivy has the tools for the job. You need to become very familiar with the ivy [settings](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings.html) file and how it declares and uses [resolvers](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/resolvers.html).

If repository is accessible via HTTPS the the [url](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/url.html) resolver should be able to access it. The resolver will assume that each version of an artifact is in a different directory and you'll need to specify the URL pattern that ivy will need to use when accessing the repository:

```
<url name="two-patterns-example">
  <ivy pattern="http://ivyrep.mycompany.com/[module]/[revision]/ivy-[revision].xml" />
  <artifact pattern="http://ivyrep.mycompany.com/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
</url>
```

The pattern is fully flexible to how you store the artifacts.

Authentication is also handled in the settings file using the [credentials](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/credentials.html) tag.

Finally, the FTP protocol is also supported. It's hard to find in the doco, but it's supported by the [vfs](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/vfs.html) resolver.

I think that's enough information on an option I don't recommend :-)  Having said that I once created an FTP based repository for managing releases to clients. It's useful to have a tool this powerful :-)