# Managing and importing Ivy artifacts from global Maven repositories

Tags: java, maven, ant, ivy

My company runs an internal Ivy repository over a NAS. There we put all the dependencies for our projects. A few days ago, the repo has been rebuilt completely from scratch, using a combination of Java code and calls to Ant task `ivy-install`.

I personally designed and performed the rebuilding, but faced an important issue. While I used [mvrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com) as reference for importing common open source projects (e.g. Spring, Hibernate), often packages were available in not-widely-known Maven repositories I had to Google for.

Every time (e.g. with `hibernate-spatial`) I found a package belonging to an "unknown" Maven source I had to some manual work by registering the remote source into `ivy-settings.xml` and manually run again `ivy-install`.

This made me think: does it even exist a tool that graphically (e.g. web interface) helps Ivy administrator **search** and download to local repository artifacts from multiple remote sources (registered by user)? Like if I type the `<dependency>` tag, or the `org`, `name` and `rev` attributes and it lists available sources. When I need to download a package to local repo, simply click and it gets published.

Comment: I personally use a Maven repository manager (Nexus) to manage my ivy dependencies. These repo managers have the ability to proxy remote repository content and maintain search indexes.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor do you mean that your repository is Maven and you get dependencies from Ivy repositories? I'm taking a look at nexus

Comment: I pull my build dependencies from a local Maven repository managed by Nexus. I also publish my build artifacts to Nexus, for use by other local projects. Best of both worlds. Maven repository managers have become a standard in Java, allows sharing between builds independent of build technology. Also avoids the need to write my own custom ivy repository management code.

Comment: See related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362453/apache-ivy-where-do-i-put-all-these-jars/